# I have a private key and wallet passphrase

Tags: private-key, funds

I have a private key and wallet passphrase generated some time ago, how do I now access my funds?

Answer (score 0):

private key is use to spend Bitcoin while  wallet passphrase is use to recover your wallet as well as generate the private key to the wallet, in order for you to use access your fund you can import the private key in to another wallet such as blockchain wallet 
watch this YouTube video for clarification 
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=03RbWB4ONFY

Comment: Hi Dprincebh, please edit existing answers instead of adding new ones, except you are providing different answers.

Answer (score -1):

kindly import the private key into another wallet such as blockchain you can access your Bitcoin there

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! To make this answer better, it would be helpful if you expanded a bit on what the private keys are for or how to import them into another wallet (for example by providing a link to some instructions for common wallets or another SE question on importing keys) :)